# Bash/Python: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character whilst piping to python

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to pipe into python using bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "from rest_framework_api_key.models import APIKey\n_, key = APIKey.objects.create_key(name='test_key')\nprint(key)" | python manage.py shell
```

This gives the following error:

```
    from rest_framework_api_key.models import APIKey\n_, key = APIKey.objects.create_key(name='test_key')\nprint(key)
                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Strangely, this works:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "from users.models import CustomUser\nCustomUser.objects.create_superuser('foo', '$1')" | python manage.py shell
```

And I can't see the difference in terms of new lines / escaping / quoting. If I remove the pipe to python (i.e. it runs only the echo command), it does not error.

Comment: Whether `\n` sequences are honored by `echo` depends on your specific implementation of `sh`. It's safer to use `printf`, which works on all compliant shells.

Comment: In the failed case, `\n` is being passed as two characters rather than replaced with a single newline.

Comment: That said, it's extremely bad security practice to inject data into code via string substitution. Safer to use `sys.argv` to get arguments even in Python scripts embedded in bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, it's temporary ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash`'s `echo` doesn't expand `\n` to a newline by default. Use `printf`:

```
printf "from rest_framework_api_key.models import APIKey\n_, key = APIKey.objects.create_key(name='test_key')\nprint(key)" | python manage.py shell
```

or more simply, a here document:

```
python manage.py shell << EOF
from rest_framework_api_key.models import APIKey
_, key = APIKey.objects.create_key(name='test_key')
print(key)
EOF
```

Comment: Any guesses why the first script worked, but this one didn't?

Comment: I'd guess you ran them in different shells. If one ran with a `/bin/sh` provided by bash and the other with dash, there's your difference.

Comment: `bash` 3.2, at least, treats `echo` differently if invoked as `/bin/sh`, as your shebang implies. I don't recall which 4.x release changed that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *-e* flag in the echo.

It should be :

```
echo -e "from rest_framework_api_key.models import APIKey\n_, key = APIKey.objects.create_key(name='test_key')\nprint(key)"
```

Let me know if it helps!

Note : I only now noticed the shebang in your code. Unless you have a very specific reason not to do so, you should change your **#!/bin/sh** for **#!/bin/bash**.

Comment: -e is not a supported feature for baseline implementations of /bin/sh; it's an extension that requires bash/ksh/zsh/etc.

Comment: See the POSIX sh `echo` specification at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: (actually, it's not even an extension; extensions *extend* the standard without violating any of its requirements, but the standard's plain text requires `echo -e` to print `-e` on output).

Comment: I agree with everything you said @CharlesDuffy. But I only now noticed the shebang. Probably OP does not even need to use *sh* and can instead use *bash*. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Even bash does not always honor `echo -e`; its behavior differs on whether the `xpg_echo` flag is set, which can be done at any of runtime, compile time, or enabled via inherited environment variables.